# How to prevent the application is closed, when I close the server socket.

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, thread-safety

I created a server-client application using the asynchronous socket. I found the problem when closing a socket on the server, applications so closed. The procedure that I do to close the socket server is:

1. Terminate the listening thread.
2. Close the client socket is still connected to the server.
3. Close the server socket.

How to prevent the application is closed, when I close the server socket? Thanks

```
    Protected Friend Sub CloseServerSocket(ByVal IPAddress As IPAddress, ByVal socketPort As Integer)

    ' Terminate the listening thread. 
    If listeningThread.IsAlive Then listeningThread.Abort()

    ' Close the client socket is still connected to the server.
    For Each sock As Socket In workSocketList
        If sock.Connected Then
            Interlocked.Decrement(workCount)
            sock.Close()
        End If
    Next

    ' Close the server socket.
    serverSocket.Close()
    serverSocket = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried swapping step 2 with 3 and succeed. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Friend Sub CloseServerSocket(ByVal IPAddress As IPAddress, ByVal socketPort As Integer)

' Terminate the listening thread. 
If listeningThread.IsAlive Then listeningThread.Abort()

' Close the server socket.
serverSocket.Close()
serverSocket = Nothing

' Close the client socket is still connected to the server.
For Each sock As Socket In workSocketList
    If sock.Connected Then
        Interlocked.Decrement(workCount)
        sock.Close()
    End If
Next

End Sub
```